# Match & replace within multiple quoted strings with REGEX

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace all spaces within quotes with underscores in R. I'm not sure how to define the quoted strings correctly when there are more than one. My starting  effort fails, and I haven't even got on to single/double quotes.

```
require(stringi)
s = "The 'quick brown' fox 'jumps over' the lazy dog"
stri_replace_all(s, regex="('.*) (.*')", '$1_$2')
#> [1] "The 'quick brown' fox 'jumps_over' the lazy dog"
```

Grateful for help.

Comment: Only if you have a tawdry mind ;)

Comment: Do you need to account for escape sequences inside? Are you dealing with properly escaped strings? If you can match whole relevant `'....'` substrings, then you may replace any text within the matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume you need to match all non-overlapping substrings that start with `'`, then have 1 or more chars other than `'` and then end with `'`. The pattern is [`'[^']+'`](https://regex101.com/r/Xd4lE9/1).

Then, you may use the following base R code:

```
x = "The 'quick cunning brown' fox 'jumps up and over' the lazy dog"
gr <- gregexpr("'[^']+'", x)
mat <- regmatches(x, gr)
regmatches(x, gr) <- lapply(mat, gsub, pattern="\\s", replacement="_")
x
## => [1] "The 'quick_cunning_brown' fox 'jumps_up_and_over' the lazy dog"
```

See [this R demo](http://ideone.com/bNQuY3). Or, use `gsubfn`:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> rx <- "'[^']+'"
> s = "The 'quick cunning brown' fox 'jumps up and over' the lazy dog"
> gsubfn(rx, ~ gsub("\\s", "_", x), s)
[1] "The 'quick_cunning_brown' fox 'jumps_up_and_over' the lazy dog"
>
```

To support escape sequences, you may use a much more complex PCRE regex:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\K'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'
```

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\)` - no `\` immediately before the current location
- `(?:\\{2})*` - zero or more sequences of 2 `\`s
- `\K` - *match reset* operator
- `'` - a single quote
- `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any char but a newline
  - `[^'\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`
- `'` - a single quote.

And the [R demo](http://ideone.com/mVzCxj) would look like

```
x = "The \\' \\\\\\' \\\\\\\\'quick \\'cunning\\' brown' fox 'jumps up \\'and\\' over' the lazy dog"
cat(x, sep="\n")
gr <- gregexpr("(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\{2})*\\K'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'", x, perl=TRUE)
mat <- regmatches(x, gr)
regmatches(x, gr) <- lapply(mat, gsub, pattern="\\s", replacement="_")
cat(x, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
The \' \\\' \\\\'quick \'cunning\' brown' fox 'jumps up \'and\' over' the lazy dog
The \' \\\' \\\\'quick_\'cunning\'_brown' fox 'jumps_up_\'and\'_over' the lazy dog
```

Comment: I had the same idea - I don't know if there is any advantage to saving `mat` separately as you have to run `regmatches` twice anyway though. +1 regardless - `regmatches<-` is really a very useful function.

Comment: Yes, I also think base R, with PCRE regex option, is very powerful, and is the only most convenient option when you have to deal with escape sequences (see the update).

Comment: Comprehensive, thanks Wiktor. I'm not gong to pretend to understand the PCRE example..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require(stringi)
s = "The 'quick brown' fox 'jumps over' the lazy dog"
stri_replace_all(s, regex="('[a-z]+) ([a-z]+')", '$1_$2')
```

Comment: This assumes there is only one space between `'`+`letters` and `letters`+`'`.

Comment: This won't work for more than two words within quotes.

Comment: I think .* is too greedy. That's why being specific - going for letters might help. You'll need to modify if the strings you have are capital letters or special characters.

Comment: I understood that by 'only one' the meaning was only one pair of words in quotes. If it meant more than one space, try this:
  `stri_replace_all(s, regex="('[a-z]+) +([a-z]+')", '$1_$2')`